# grunt installing unrequested dependencies

Tags: macos, gruntjs, npm-install

When I install grunt into a local folder it appears to be loading 88 dependencies I did not request. Is this normal?

If I use a packages.json file and and perform an pm install it won't install grunt, but everything else.

```html
npm install grunt --save-dev
npm WARN install Usage of the `--dev` option is deprecated. Use `--only=dev` instead.
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/xxxx/Desktop/grunt test/package.json'
/Users/xxxx/Desktop/grunt test
└─┬ grunt@1.0.1
  ├── coffee-script@1.10.0
  ├─┬ dateformat@1.0.12
  │ ├── get-stdin@4.0.1
  │ └─┬ meow@3.7.0
  │   ├─┬ camelcase-keys@2.1.0
  │   │ └── camelcase@2.1.1
  │   ├── decamelize@1.2.0
  │   ├─┬ loud-rejection@1.6.0
  │   │ ├─┬ currently-unhandled@0.4.1
  │   │ │ └── array-find-index@1.0.2
  │   │ └── signal-exit@3.0.2
  │   ├── map-obj@1.0.1
  │   ├── minimist@1.2.0
  │   ├─┬ normalize-package-data@2.3.5
  │   │ ├── hosted-git-info@2.2.0
  │   │ ├─┬ is-builtin-module@1.0.0
  │   │ │ └── builtin-modules@1.1.1
  │   │ ├── semver@5.3.0
  │   │ └─┬ validate-npm-package-license@3.0.1
  │   │   ├─┬ spdx-correct@1.0.2
  │   │   │ └── spdx-license-ids@1.2.2
  │   │   └── spdx-expression-parse@1.0.4
  │   ├── object-assign@4.1.1
  │   ├─┬ read-pkg-up@1.0.1
  │   │ ├─┬ find-up@1.1.2
  │   │ │ ├── path-exists@2.1.0
  │   │ │ └─┬ pinkie-promise@2.0.1
  │   │ │   └── pinkie@2.0.4
  │   │ └─┬ read-pkg@1.1.0
  │   │   ├─┬ load-json-file@1.1.0
  │   │   │ ├── graceful-fs@4.1.11
  │   │   │ ├─┬ parse-json@2.2.0
  │   │   │ │ └─┬ error-ex@1.3.1
  │   │   │ │   └── is-arrayish@0.2.1
  │   │   │ ├── pify@2.3.0
  │   │   │ └─┬ strip-bom@2.0.0
  │   │   │   └── is-utf8@0.2.1
  │   │   └── path-type@1.1.0
  │   ├─┬ redent@1.0.0
  │   │ ├─┬ indent-string@2.1.0
  │   │ │ └─┬ repeating@2.0.1
  │   │ │   └─┬ is-finite@1.0.2
  │   │ │     └── number-is-nan@1.0.1
  │   │ └── strip-indent@1.0.1
  │   └── trim-newlines@1.0.0
  ├── eventemitter2@0.4.14
  ├── exit@0.1.2
  ├─┬ findup-sync@0.3.0
  │ └── glob@5.0.15
  ├─┬ glob@7.0.6
  │ ├── fs.realpath@1.0.0
  │ ├─┬ inflight@1.0.6
  │ │ └── wrappy@1.0.2
  │ ├── inherits@2.0.3
  │ └── once@1.4.0
  ├─┬ grunt-cli@1.2.0
  │ └── resolve@1.1.7
  ├── grunt-known-options@1.1.0
  ├─┬ grunt-legacy-log@1.0.0
  │ ├── colors@1.1.2
  │ ├─┬ grunt-legacy-log-utils@1.0.0
  │ │ ├─┬ chalk@1.1.3
  │ │ │ ├── ansi-styles@2.2.1
  │ │ │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.5
  │ │ │ ├─┬ has-ansi@2.0.0
  │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.1.1
  │ │ │ ├── strip-ansi@3.0.1
  │ │ │ └── supports-color@2.0.0
  │ │ └── lodash@4.3.0
  │ ├── hooker@0.2.3
  │ ├── lodash@3.10.1
  │ └── underscore.string@3.2.3
  ├─┬ grunt-legacy-util@1.0.0
  │ ├── async@1.5.2
  │ ├── getobject@0.1.0
  │ ├── lodash@4.3.0
  │ └─┬ which@1.2.12
  │   └── isexe@1.1.2
  ├── iconv-lite@0.4.15
  ├─┬ js-yaml@3.5.5
  │ ├─┬ argparse@1.0.9
  │ │ └── sprintf-js@1.0.3
  │ └── esprima@2.7.3
  ├─┬ minimatch@3.0.3
  │ └─┬ brace-expansion@1.1.6
  │   ├── balanced-match@0.4.2
  │   └── concat-map@0.0.1
  ├─┬ nopt@3.0.6
  │ └── abbrev@1.1.0
  ├── path-is-absolute@1.0.1
  └── rimraf@2.2.8

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/grunt test/package.json'
npm WARN grunt test No description
npm WARN grunt test No repository field.
npm WARN grunt test No README data
npm WARN grunt test No license field.
```

Comment: Yes this is normal behavior. It is also installing the packages that "grunt" itself is dependent on and then recursively its dependencies dependencies and so on..

Comment: Did something change with how NPM installs packages? I feel like there were less folders in the node_modules directory the last time I created a project.